# How can Iselect lines containing "Post" in WinAutomation

Tags: regex

When I use the following expression in notepad++ it does successfully selects line that contains the word "post" in it, but when I use it in winautomation it doesn't work :(

```
^.*post.*$
```

Can someone please tell me what would be some alternative regex expression by which I can select lines that contains the word "post"

Also I am not sure if this would help or not but here is a sample expression that works in winautomation, I use it to parse urls off XML files, is this a different regex format than the one above?

```
(?<=<loc>).*?(?=</loc>)
```

Comment: Post simple data

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do with `^.*post.*$` is match `any character any number of times` followed by `post` word followed by `any character any number of times`.

A logical way would be to lookahead if `post` is present and select whole line. This is done by following regex.

**Regex:** `(?=.*post)^.*$`

**Explanation:**

`(?=.*post)` would lookahead for `any number of characters any number of time` followed by word `post`.

`^.*$` if previous assertion is true then regex will match whole line.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/E4V6UR/1/)**</kbd>